# Using framer motion 3d in conjonction with react three fiber how to rotate a 3d object while scrolling?

Tags: 3d, react-three-fiber, framer-motion

I am trying to animate a 3D cube with a  rotation while scrolling using framer motion. Can someone help me to do it? I do not understand why my cube disappears as soon as y1 is applied in the useFramer function, and how can I make the animation?

Thanks

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion-3d';
import { useMotionValueEvent, useScroll, useTransform } from 'framer-motion';

const Box = () => {
  const meshRef = useRef<THREE.Object3D>(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    // offset: ['start start', 'end start']
    // target: meshRef
  });

  useMotionValueEvent(scrollYProgress, 'change', (latest) => {
    console.log('Page scroll scrollYProgress: ', latest);
  });

  const y1 = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0, 200]);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    meshRef.current.rotation.x += y1;
  });

  return (
    <motion.mesh
      ref={meshRef}
    >
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color='blue' />
    </motion.mesh>
  );
};

const CubeFramerMotion = () => {
  return <Box />;
};

export default CubeFramerMotion;
```